# MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1'

Tags: php, forms, mysqli, isset

```html
<html>
<body>
<form method = 'post' action= 'pt.php'>
<input type = 'text' name = 'name' placeholder = 'name'><br>
<textarea name = 'comment' cols = '40' rows = '10' placeholder = 'comment'></textarea><br>
<input type = 'submit' value = 'submit' name ='submit'><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>


<?php
require 'submit.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $name= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
 $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['comment']);
 if (empty($name) || empty($comment)){
  echo "all fields must be filled<br>"; 
  }else{
   $sql=$conn->query("INSERT INTO komen (nama, komment) VALUES ('$name','$comment')");
   if($conn->query($sql) == TRUE){
    echo "berhasil ditambahkan";
   }
   else
   {
    echo "error".$sql."<br>".$conn->error;
   }
   
  }
}
  if($result=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM komen")){
   $count = $result->num_rows;
   echo 'Total '.$count.' komen <br><br>';
   while ($rows=$result->fetch_object()){
    echo '<strong>'.$rows->nama.'></strong>'.'<br>'.$rows->komment.'<br><br><br>';
   }
$conn->close();
}
?>
```

I still get error "error1
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1".

could you help me through this?
many thanks.

Comment: None of the answers given have explained why you are getting a `near '1'`. Consult the duplicate; it's explained and for you to understand "why".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it this way

```
$sql="INSERT INTO komen (nama, komment) VALUES ('$name','$comment')";
    if($conn->query($sql) == TRUE){
        echo "berhasil ditambahkan";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error".$sql."<br>".$conn->error;
    }
```

Comment: great!!problem solved. many thanks!!!

Comment: Cheers. Up vote and mark correct pls.

Answer (score -1):

Try to print your SQL statement.

```
die("INSERT INTO komen (nama, komment) VALUES ('$name','$comment')");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the following

```
$sql=$conn->query("INSERT INTO komen (nama, komment) VALUES ('$name','$comment')");
```

To

```
$sql=$conn->query("INSERT INTO komen (nama, komment) VALUES ('".$name."','".$comment."')");
```

Comment: i changed it. the $name and $comment successfully inserted but the error message still apprear instead of echoing "berhasil ditambahkan"(successfully added).

Comment: can you provide what values are you inserting in the columns

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted ?